# How do I improve Windows Subversion client update performance?

Tags: performance, svn

How do I improve Subversion client update performance? It appears to be disk bound on the client.

Details:

- CollabNet Windows client version 1.6.2 (r37639)
- Windows XP SP2
- 3 GB RAM with PF Usage around 1 GB and System Cache of 1.1 GB.
- Disk has write caching enabled
- Update takes 7-15 minutes (when very little to update).
- Checkout has 36,083 directories/files (from svn list)
- Repository has 58,750 revisions.
- Checkout takes about 2.7 GB
- Perf monitor shows % Disk Write time stays near 90% during update.
- Max Disk Read Bytes/sec got up to 12.8M and write got up to 5.2M
- CPU, paging file usage, and network usage are all low.
- Watching the server performance seems to show that it isn't a bottleneck.

I'm especially interested in answers besides getting a faster disk (especially configuration changes).

Updates from some of the suggestions:

- I need the whole thing so sparse directories won't work.
- Another client (TortoiseSVN) takes 7 minutes also
- TortoiseSVN icon overlays have be configured so they don't cause the problem.
- Anti-virus is configured to to skip that directory is it isn't causing the problem.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're probably all over this already, but anti-virus programs like McAffee and AVG will scan on every disk read/write.

Comment: I experience the same problems when running under Windows. Linux clients are 5 times faster on a fresh checkout, using similar hardware. Info I have seen blames it on the windows disk access being inefficient, with no way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[TortoiseSVN file overlay performance - are there any ways of improving it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525829/tortoisesvn-file-overlay-performance-are-there-any-ways-of-improving-it)*.

Answer (score 2):

I experience exatly the same thing. Recently replaced Perforce with svn, but if we cannot overcome the performance problems on Windows me must consider another tool.
Using svn 1.6.6, Win XP and Vista clients. RedHat server.
My observations matches yours:

- Huge disk-write activity.
- Antivirus not a bottleneck.
- No matter witch svn-clients are used.
- No server or network bottleneck.

Complementary info
More than 3 times faster operations on:

- Linux (Ubuntu).
- Linux (Ubuntu) running on VirtualBox at Win Vista host.
- Win XP running on VMWare at RedHat host.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need every bit of the repository on your working copy?  If you truly only care about particular portions of the tree, look into Subversion's [**Sparse Directories**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) (a.k.a. "Sparse Checkouts") feature.  It allows you to manipulate your working copy so it only contains those directories of interest.

Just as an example, you might use this to prune documentation, installer-related files, etc.  Depending on what you truly need on your local machine, embracing this approach could make a serious dent in your wait times.

Answer (score 1):

Try svn client version 1.5.*. It helped me on my Vista laptop. Versions 1.6.* are extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely to be your network and the amount of data moved as well as your client.  Are you using Tortoise?  I find it to be a bit slow myself when moving that much data!

Comment: I am not using Tortoise but the CollabNet command line client.  Also perf monitor showed very low network usage.  Is they anything else specific that I should check to see if it is a network issue?

Comment: You could create a repository on a local computer check in your code there. If it's a network issue it should go lots faster if it's local.

But my guess it's a disk issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TortoiseSVN?  If so, the Icon Overlays do slow down operations.  If you go to TortoiseSVN Settings/Icon Overlays there are several settings you can tweak to control the level to which you want to use the Overlays, including turning them off completely.  See if that affects your performance.

Comment: I have already tweaked them to use shell so that I wouldn't get a hit from its background processing.  I just tested turning them off completely and it took 7 minutes so it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run a virus checker that uses on-access scanning? That can really make it crawl. If so, turn it off and see if that helps. Most scanners will have a way to exclude specific directories if that helps.

Comment: I already had it configured to ignore the directory with my checkouts.  As a test I disabled it completely and it still took 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to be pointing out the one reason that I often consider a design flaw.  Subversion creates a second "pristine" copy of the checkout for offline operations.  If you're checking out 4G of files, it's actually writing 8G to disk.

Compare a checkout to an export.  That will show you the massive difference when writing those second copies.

There's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: That probably doesn't affect update performance.  BTW that "design flaw" enables diffs while disconnected from the server so it does have a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to svn 1.7

From [Discussion of Slow Performance of SVN Update](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=339491):

> The update process in svn 1.6 goes something like this:
>
> 1. search the entire working copy, to see what's there at the moment, and locking it so no one changes the answer during the next steps
> 2. tell that to the server
> 3. receive from the server whatever new stuff you need, applying the changes to the files as you go
> 4. recurse over the entire working copy again, unlocking it
>
> If there are many directories and files, steps 1 and 4 can take up a
>   lot of time. This would be consistent with your observation of long
>   delays with no network traffic.

Working copy format was changed in svn 1.7. Now all meta information is stored in SQLite database in root folder of working copy and there is no need to perform steps 1 and 4 any more which consumed most of the time durring `svn update`.